# How to fix "TypeError: (0 , _web.default) is not a function" in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a problem with Express. This is my code

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { configViewEngine } from "./config/viewEngine.js";
import { initWebRoutes } from './route/web.js';
import connectDB from "./config/connectDB.js";
import cors from 'cors';
require('dotenv').config();
let app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
configViewEngine(app);
initWebRoutes(app);
connectDB();
let port = process.env.PORT || 7070;

//if port is undefined, default to current 7070
app.listen(port, () => {
    //callback
    console.log("BE NodeJS is running on the port" + port);
})
```

I run project and receive a bug with content:

> "TypeError: (0 , _web.default) is not a function"

I'm expecting my code work normally